# What does it mean when gltf does not specify a skeleton value in a skin?

Tags: c++, json, animation, graphics, gltf

Reading the source code of tinygltf I see this:

```
struct Skin {
  std::string name;
  int inverseBindMatrices;  // required here but not in the spec
  int skeleton;             // The index of the node used as a skeleton root
  std::vector<int> joints;  // Indices of skeleton nodes

  Value extras;
  ExtensionMap extensions;

  // Filled when SetStoreOriginalJSONForExtrasAndExtensions is enabled.
  std::string extras_json_string;
  std::string extensions_json_string;

  Skin() {
    inverseBindMatrices = -1;
    skeleton = -1;
  }
  DEFAULT_METHODS(Skin)
  bool operator==(const Skin &) const;
};
```

That would made you assume that the skeleton value is mandatory. However, on the gltf simple skin example json, I see the following:

```
  "skins" : [ {
    "inverseBindMatrices" : 4,
    "joints" : [ 1, 2 ]
  } ],
```

That's the full extent of the `skins` array. So it seems it is perfectly possible for a skin not to specify which one is the root node of its skeleton. In that case, which node in the joints array should I treat at the parent? Can I safely assume it is the first element of the `joints` list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the glTF specification](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/blob/master/specification/2.0/README.md#skinskeleton), `skin.skeleton` is "the closest common root of the joints hierarchy or a direct or indirect parent node of the closest common root."

Not all engines or authoring tools have a concept of a "root" in the joint hierarchy, so it isn't required, but if your loader needs one you can simply choose any node that is a common ancestor of the other joints, use the scene root itself, or insert a new root at loading time.

Comment: Yes. I'll highlight the part about some loaders not needing a "root" joint.  If a given rendering engine doesn't bother to draw any distinction between a "node" and a "bone" (joint), then it doesn't need to even look at the skeleton field, or care if it's missing.  It can still animate a skin correctly without that.